# converting column type in dataframe in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe in spark:

```
column1 | column2
-------------------
 a         1
 b         2
```

Both, column1 and column2 are of type string.

How can I convert column2 from string to big int?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to cast your column to a bigint or a long (which is the same in Spark)

```
val df = sc
    .parallelize(Seq(("a", "1"), ("b", "2")))
    .toDF("A", "B")
df.printSchema
root
     |-- A: string (nullable = true)
     |-- B: string (nullable = true)


df.withColumn("B", 'B cast "bigint").printSchema
```

or

```
df.withColumn("B", 'B cast "long").printSchema
root
     |-- A: string (nullable = true)
     |-- B: long (nullable = true)
```